# Can't kill a chrome extension process at times

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

For testing purposes, I find the service worker process of my chrome extension and then kill it. This causes chrome to restart the service worker with a new PID. I find that process (after a delay) and try to kill it again. However this time, it doesn't work. I have tried 2 approaches:

- Terminate the process using chrome.processes API available to extensions. This returns false for the process. NOTE: That you will have to pass special flags to enable this in Chrome stable.
- Force kill the process using node.js `process.kill(PID, 'SIGKILL')`. This never throws any error and the call seems to just hang there.

Any ideas what could cause a process to not die? I understand that by trying-to-kill we are actually just passing a signal to the process and it can choose not to kill itself. However, since it works the first time, but not the second time around, it's baffling me about what could be going on here.

Comment: Terminating the process externally should work, so apparently there's a bug in Chrome or in node. Try removing `'SIGKILL'`. A workaround would be to use [CDP command ServiceWorker.stopWorker](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/ServiceWorker/#method-stopWorker) using a cdp library for node.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm, could you help me with using CDP way of stopping service worker. I can get it by creating a CDP session, and asking for all targets using `Target.getTargets`. From here I can filter to find the service worker that I want to kill, but I am not sure how to use `ServiceWorker.stopWorker`. I can do `Target.closeTarget` though. Thoughts?

Comment: closeTarget should work I guess.